# Website displaying differently on Chrome vs Internet Explorer

Tags: php, html, mobile-website

My website is working fine on Internet explorer is still fine. Here is a print where you can see the top menu.

[image: website on internet explorer]

However, on Chrome the top menu has disappeared. Instead I have this red bar and must click the "MENU" button to see the top menu...(before it was working fine on Chrome):
[image: website on Chrome]

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Kind regards

Comment: Because IE and Chrome have very different HTML rendering engines. IE's is years out of date and fails to adhere to a lot of the modern web standards, so it often displays things differently. If you've primarily been developing and testing your site in IE, you're at least a decade behind the times. I.E. is hardly used now, a lot of sites don't even bother to support it. You should target modern browsers first, and get it looking nice, and if you really _need_ to support IE you can always add some IE-specific CSS or whatever to tweak it.

Comment: Having said all that, your first screenshot looks like the Edge browser, not Internet Explorer at all! The newest version of Edge uses the same rendering engine as Chrome, so it'd be fairly surprising if a site looked very different in the two. However if you haven't upgraded and still have the older Edge, it does have its own rendering engine, and while it's not as outdated as IE's (by a long way) there might still be the odd issue or incompatibility.

Comment: We can't suggest any fixes though without knowing the versions of each browser you're using, and without seeing enough HTML and CSS code (and JS, if relevant) to form a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: *"the top menu has disappeared ... and must click the "MENU" button to see the top menu"* ... sounds like a media query

Comment: Your chrome example is clearly zoomed in. that will decrease the width of your screen and trigger the phone or tablet display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element `body > div.slicknav_menu.hidden-lg` has the CSS class `hidden-lg` that comes from **Bootstrap** which triggers `{ display: none; }` after a screen width of `>=1200px`

**So there is no issue with your website**

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

[image]

[image]

[image]